# Response Status undefined in Client-Server-Communication - JavaScript, NodeJS, Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, knex.js

I have an issue with server-client-communication using express in javascript.
The following case:
The user inserts information (new user name and password) in form. If the name is already taken (exists in the database) the user gets an alert that it is already taken.

My idea was to do that via status requests:

Code on Client Side:

```
        //Send request for database
        post('/login/createUser', { username, password, role })
        .then((response)=>
        {
            //Case: Name does not yet exist in DB
            if(response.status == 200)
            //Inform that new user was added

            //Case: Name does exist in DB
            if(response.status == 105)
            //Inform that new user was not added

        })
```

I use the following post function:

```
function post(path, data) {
    return window.fetch(path, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
  }
```

Code on Server-Side:

```
router.post('/createUser', (req, res) => {
    store
        .createUser({
            username: req.body.username,
            password: req.body.password,
            role: req.body.role
        })
        .then(() => 
        {
            console.log(`Add user ${req.body.username} as ${req.body.role}`);
            res.sendStatus(200);
        }
        ).catch(() => 
        {   
            console.log(`Failed to add user ${req.body.username}, already exists`);
            res.status(105).send(`User exstis`);
            res.end();
        })
});
```

Code in store:

```
//User Stuff
  createUser({ username, password, role }) {

    const { salt, hash } = saltHashPassword({ password })
    return knex('user').insert({
          salt,
          encrypted_password: hash,
          username,
          role
        })


  },
```

The issue is that on client-side the response.status is undefined when I try to add a user that is already taken. Hence I would have to handle the case in a catch, which results in a longer waiting time for the user.
Why does my status approach not work?

Comment: Are you sure you are accesing the status in the right property? What does `console.log(response)` print? Also why are you using `105`? `400 Bad Request` or `409 Conflict` make more sense. All `4xx` status mean that the error is in the client side

Comment: Thanks for the comment on the status number. 

If I insert a user with already existing name console.log(response) prints: TypeError: Failed to fetch
Furthermore I get the error: 
post.js:2 POST http://localhost:3000/login/createUser net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

If I insert user with new name it prints: [object Response] and response status 200

Comment: You are returning an empty reponse in `res.sendStatus(200);`. Could it be the cause?

Comment: Update:
The Error-message was wrong:
 res.status(105).send(`User exstis`); cannot be written with `` but has to be written with ''
I don't know why, but now it works

Comment: Both are strings... Should be something else. But nice to know it works now